# What happens when a servlet is requested?

Tags: java, servlets

I know that when a servlet is requested, the init(), service() and destroy() are called consecutively .When a servlet is requested, a thread is created for every request. So, for each thread the whole servlet context is initialized like all the context-params and init-param are set again?

Comment: You seem to be **very** confused about the servlet life cycle. `init` and `destroy` are called *once* (on deployment *or* undeployment respectively). In between these two states, zero (or more) threads may execute the `service` method (the "requests").

Answer (score 1):

> I know that when a servlet is requested, the init(), service() and destroy() are called consecutively.

No you don't. The servlet is initialized and destroyed along with the container, exactly once in its lifecycle. Not per request.

> When a servlet is requested, a thread is created for every request.

No it isn't. A thread is more usually allocated from a thread pool.

> So, for each thread the whole servlet context is initialized like all the context-params and init-param are set again?

No. See above.